# How to store python logging outputs into mongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb, logging

This is example of what i want to do. If i am able to store output of logging.warning() into a variable i will be able to store it into the Mongodb

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,filename='logDemo.log')
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

def divide(a,b):
    try :

        divide = a/b
        return divide
    except ZeroDivisionError:           

    a=logging.warning('Watch out!') # will print a message to the console
    logging.info('I told you so') # will not print anything
    logging.warning('is when this event was logged.')        
    print a


divide(60,0)
```

**I have tried to store the output of logging.warning() into a variable but it failed, Can there is a way to store logging functions output into mongodb**

Comment: What has this to do with MongoDB? There is no single line of MongoDB related code?! and fix your code formatting and indentation... In addition: how can you come to the conclusion that the logger module can be used for storing message in variables?

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to write your own MongoDBLoggingHandler and implementing an emit() method dealing with the MongoDB specific 
saving. See

http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html